# How can i redirect analytics url traffic via a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, analytics, http-status-code-301

I got a url of this type

http://www.stackoverflow.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=bla&utm_term=blabla&utm_content=test&utm_campaign=301

I want ALL traffic that lands on that specific url to be redirected to another website

The problem is when i setup a 301 it redirects all website and not only that SPECIFIC url

That means if my domain is

stackoverflow.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=bla&utm_term=blabla&utm_content=test&utm_campaign=301

to

newsite.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=bla&utm_term=blabla&utm_content=test&utm_campaign=301

Instead of that i also get redirections of the stackoverflow.com-->newsite.com

Is there a way to make this work just for that url?

Thanks